# Mongodb fails to shard collection with "found missing value in key"

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Need quick help on this. For the life of me, I can't figure out why MongoDB fails to shard the collection, stating that there is a null value for the given shard key.

I'm trying to create shards based on the first tag element in the documents, hence the key is tags[0]. To clarify, in this instance, the value I'm pointing at is "fc4f03a4-0f7b-5cf4-af4e-8b38377a9e34".

```
mongos> sh.shardCollection("mydb.logs", { "tags[0]": 1 } );
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "found missing value in key { : null } for doc: { _id: \"8f0f90bd-e63e-521f-a637-b773f3eefdf0\", tags: [ \"fc4f03a4-0f7b-5cf4-af4e-8b38377a9e34\", \"Converter\" ], date: new Date(1531180801464), account: \"1aff2ce3-b510-525a-86ff-e379fac03f8c\", data: \"Converter has been initialized.\", __v: 0 }"
}
```

Clearly, tags[0] is not null. Why is MongoDB behaving this way?

Answer (score 0):

Changing it into dot notation worked.

mongos> sh.shardCollection("mydb.logs", { "tags.0": 1 } );

I'm still not sure why it doesn't accept the first notation [], though.